# Querying a view that retrieves data from a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an emergency for which i must give a reply in short time.

I wrote an application that allows the user to query a single sql server db (MyDB from now on).

I assumed that to query other dbs (Oracles, csv, ...) the trick was:

1) creating a linked server on the same server wher the MyDB is

2) on MyDb creating a view that somehow selects data from a table on the linked server

Now I am not sure that (2) is possible. i am trying to create a linked server with Excel but with failure, this is why I asked also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274079/simplest-way-to-create-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-2008r2).

So my question is:

is it possible to run

```
select * from VIEW_WITH_DATA_FROM_LINKED_SERVER
```

if the connection is made to MyDB and `VIEW_WITH_DATA_FROM_LINKED_SERVER` is a view belonging to MyDb?

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow my goal is to "hide the fact that the linked server exists" thanks to the view, so to put all the connection info about the linked server inside the view. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view using linked server by below query.

USE [SNHU_Reporting]
GO

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE view [dbo].[VIEW_WITH_DATA_FROM_LINKED_SERVER] AS
SELECT * FROM [Servername].db_name.dbo.tablename --dbo is the schema name.
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea, anyway Servername is not ok. I tried on same server and it is working, on different servername (i am logged in with win auth and i have access rights on all servers). If I use MyServer I have this error Could not find server 'MyServer' in sys.servers

Comment: Solved adding a linked server to a MSSQLServer. IN that case the error disappears